# Django Gunicorn got error Request Line is too large

Tags: nginx, django

I'm just a new to it. I've been trying to deploy a Django Project on Digitalocean, It worked fine except there was one url that thrown an error: *Request Line is too large (4583 > 4094)*
As I know that I should update the config **limit_request_line** for Gunicorn, but I just don't know how to do it.
Can someone help me?
Many many thanks in advance,

Comment: How are you running it?  Do you have a dedicated runner application, or are you using `gunicorn` on the command line?  You might have to set the line you're looking to set with a custom runner, (see this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40625360/how-to-set-gunicorn-limit-request-line-parameter-over-8190)

Comment: Noted thanks bro